# javascript comparison, which one is correct and why?

Tags: javascript, performance

Is there any Difference between

```
if(! (xyz === abc) ) {
}
```

AND

```
if( xyz  !== abc ) {
}
```

if both are same, which one should we prefer?

Comment: The second. One operation goes faster then two, but some compilers may optimize it, so care about readability first, just optimize code that isnt running smooth. Not to note that the second one is three bytes shorter!! :/ ;)

Comment: same, prefer 2nd, as there are less brackets

Comment: I prefer the second because I think it's more legible

Comment: Hint: Under what conditions, if any, is a test for equality faster or slower than a test for inequality?